# Angular drag and drop to different list Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on a football club app.

One to many relationship from `Match` to `Teams` and `Team` belongs to one match only.
Many to many relationship with `Team` and `User` table.

```
Matches
id    |  date   | active

Teams

id    | name   | deleted


Team_User
id    | team_id | user_id
```

Data about upcoming match teams and players are receive in following format from API

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Blue Team",
    "match_id": 52,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 33,
            "name": "Lizeth"
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "name": "Lizeth"
        },
    ]
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "White Team",
    "match_id": 52,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Lizeth"
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Lizeth"
        },
    ]
}
```

I display them in a reorder list like following but instead of dragging only one player of a team it reorders whole team in list.

```
<!-- The reorder gesture is disabled by default, enable it to drag and drop items -->
<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="doReorder($event)" disabled="false" id="reorder">
<ion-list *ngFor="let team of teams">
    <ion-list-header>
        {{ team.name }}
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-reorder>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let user of team.users; index as i;">
            <ion-note slot="start">{{ i + 1 }}</ion-note>
            <ion-label>{{ user.name }}</ion-label>
            <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-reorder>
</ion-list>
</ion-reorder-group>
```

How can I move player from one list to the other?

Thank you